# bootstrap typeahead not working, how to debug

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

this is the code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'countries',
       local: ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Bugatti', 'Ferrari', 'Ford', 'Lamborghini', 'Mercedes Benz', 'Porsche', 'Rolls-Royce', 'Volkswagen']
    });
});  
</script>
<body>
    <div class="bs-example">
        <h2>Enter your country name</h2>
        <input type="text" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
    </div>
</body>
```

copied directly from an example page.
on the original page, this code works, but it doesnt on my server.
I was trying to make a search form with typeahead capabilities, but after many tries I just copied/pasted from a web example and it didnt work either.

Comment: So there are obvious questions and debug steps here that you can do to help us out: Have you verified that the typehead library JS file is loading and not 404'ing? Are you sure the jQuery library is loading and not 404'ing? Are there any script errors? Are there any markup warnings or errors? Don't assume examples are always 100% working and accurate. Are there other libraries you're using conflicting with this? Have you used a browser/JS debugger to step through the code to make sure it's running? We can't do all of this for you, so please add more details to your question.

Comment: I did check all that. I downloaded the latest typeahead, use the cdn for jquery to make sure I was using the latest version. no more libraries, My code didnt work and to be sure I used some example from the web. Just the minimun lines, the 2 libraries and the script. that is all.